# Can I change the search engine used by Start Search in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, windows-search

While Cortana is not available in my region, I can see the integrated web searchs in Windows 10's start search being super useful if they weren't Bing results.

I'd really like to be able to change the search engine used to DuckDuckGo, is there a way I can do that?